# using 2 links to power one jquery ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#link1').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?do=link1',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      blahblah
    },
  });
});
```

how would i make this more universal?

i wish to have multiple links, going into one ajax call, but url changes using the id of the link that called it... (hope that makes sense)

i.e

```
<a href="#" id="ajax-doit1"> one </a> 
<a href="#" id="ajax-doit2"> two </a>
```

if the id starts with "ajax-" then call ajax, and ajax changes the url depending on the part after "ajax-"
so ajax-doit1 will have a url of index.php?do=doit1

is this possible?

sorry if silly question, new to jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

html:

```
<a href="index.php?do=link1" id="ajax-doit1"> one </a>
<a href="index.php?do=link2" id="ajax-doit2"> two </a>
```

Script:

```
$("a[id^='ajax-']").click(function() {
   var link=this.href;
   $.ajax({
      url: link,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {blahblah},
   });
});
```

$("a[id^='ajax-']") selects the links with an id that starts with "ajax-".

[Update] To get the text after "ajax-" change this line:

```
var link='index.php?do='+this.id.replace(/ajax-/,"");
```

Comment: Kudos for providing a jquery based solution, although it is not 100% i was looking for,
can you get the text AFTER "ajax-" instead of href?

Comment: Thanks, works fine in jsfiddle, and perfectly what i was looking for, although locally it is not working, something on my end :S

Answer (score 0):

To generalize, you could add a function that itself returns a function:

```
function makeEvent(linkName) {
   return function() {
     $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?do=' + linkName,
       type: 'POST',
       success: function(data) {
         blahblah
       },
     });
   }
}

$('#link1').click(makeEvent('link1'))
$('#link2').click(makeEvent('link2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="ajax" id="ajax-doit1"> one </a> 
<a href="#" class="ajax" id="ajax-doit2"> two </a>
```

JS:

```
$('.ajax').click(function() {
   var suffix = $(this).attr('id').substr(5);
   $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?do='+suffix,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      blahblah
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
       $('a').click(function() {
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           var link = id.split('-');
           $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?do='+link[1],
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
              blahblah
            },
          });
        });
```